# android intent and dialogbox

Tags: java, android

got another question as a new android developer I am.

I got confused on how the intent works. can I only send a single string to the next activity?

what I want to do is use a dialog box with any number of text fields, whether that is 2 or next time is 4. After the user types in those 2 or 4 or any number of text fields, assign their content to textviews in another activity. at the moment i made the dialog box appear on the 2nd activity in the OnCreate method, but everytime  I rotate the screen to landscape or portrait the dialogbox keeps coming up automaticaly.

let me know if u need further info.

thanks in advance,

Angelos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues going on here.

> can I only send a single string to the next activity?

No.  You can pass multiple objects between activities through the bundle in the intent.  Keep in mind, though, that for more complicated data structures, [you'll want to use one of these methods described in the android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3)

As for your second issue:

> but everytime I rotate the screen to landscape or portrait the
>   dialogbox keeps coming up automaticaly.

The default behavior for your activity when you rotate the device is to call the onCreate() again.  [Read the part in the android documentation about handling orientation change.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) you can pass multiple object via intent.
if your dialog list item not send try to use `ArrayList`.
Pass `Arraylist` via intent.

2)For avoid call `OnCreate` while orientation change.
Try below code.

In Activity tag of manifest write

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```